# How do I find a bug when findbugs reports "Line: -1, Type: NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH"

Tags: findbugs

anyone ever run into the problem where findbugs reports a -1 for the line?

```
File: foo.java, Line: -1, Type: NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH, Priority: Normal, Category: CORRECTNESS  here
```

Comment: Can you share your class? Or extract a minimum example?

Comment: I can't.  I can tell you that the fix was to add a finally block which closed a file handle if it wasn't null to a try-catch.

I was concerned with the line # -1 mostly.   Could this be a general problem with reporting errors for try-catch where a finally is needed?